# How to display the image name in the link

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow

I have here a code where you can display a random image but I want to show the name of the image in the link of my website. Example: mywebsite.com/random.html=funnycat.png (or something like that)
Here is my code
It would be nice if someone could help me with that problem. Also is it even posible with HTML or do I need php?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <script>
    function display_random_image() 
    {
     var theImages = [{
        src: 
        "http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3691/11268502654_f28f05966c_m.jpg",
        width: "240",
        height: "160"
      }, {
        src: "http://farm1.staticflickr.com/33/45336904_1aef569b30_n.jpg",
        width: "320",
        height: "195"
        }, {
        src: "http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5211/5384592886_80a512e2c9.jpg",
        width: "500",
        height: "343"
       }];

        var preBuffer = [];
       for (var i = 0, j = theImages.length; i < j; i++) {
          preBuffer[i] = new Image();
        preBuffer[i].src = theImages[i].src;
        preBuffer[i].width = theImages[i].width;
        preBuffer[i].height = theImages[i].height;
        }

        // create random image number
        function getRandomInt(min,max) 
         {
      //  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;

imn = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    return preBuffer[imn];
    }  

// 0 is first image,   preBuffer.length - 1) is  last image

var newImage = getRandomInt(0, preBuffer.length - 1);

// remove the previous images
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
var l = images.length;
for (var p = 0; p < l; p++) {
    images[0].parentNode.removeChild(images[0]);
}
// display the image  
document.body.appendChild(newImage);
}
    </script>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Display a random image.</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {margin-top: 30px;}
</style> 
</head>
<body>
<div>
<button id="jsstyle" 
onclick="display_random_image();">Show Image</button> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this on your example.

```
  preBuffer[i].title = theImages[i].src;
```

Comment: where should I paste it?

Comment: In your for loop  `for (var i = 0, j = theImages.length; i < j; i++) {
          preBuffer[i] = new Image();
        preBuffer[i].src = theImages[i].src;
        preBuffer[i].width = theImages[i].width;
        preBuffer[i].height = theImages[i].height;
        }`

Comment: OK then sorry that I can not help you